Trying to dynamically import MUI icon fails with type error, seemingly due to string interpolation in the import path
I have a vite react project and I'm using MUI and typescript.
I'm trying to do dynamic icon import but it results in a type error. If I try without the string interpolation and provide a static string it works. However, there are like 2k icons and I would like to avoid a static mapping if possible...
Here's my code:
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function DynamicIcon(props: { iconName: string }) {
  const [IconComponent, setIconComponent] = useState<any>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadIcon = async () => {
      if (props.iconName) {
        try {
          const { default: Icon } = await import(
            `@mui/icons-material/${props.iconName}`
          );
          setIconComponent(<Icon />);
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Failed to load icon:", error);
        }
      }
    };

    loadIcon();
  }, [props.iconName]);

  if (!IconComponent) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  return <div>{IconComponent}</div>;
}

Here's the errors:


Perhaps you're calling the DynamicIcon function with incorrect props? I don't think this code is enough for us to troubleshoot your error, also could you please add your error screen?

Updated my post. The props are correct, I've doubled checked and also tested. Thanks!
